# QByteArray to QBitArray to QbyteArray to QString + Unicode characters

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

Help please with these conversions. This is input;

```
QByteArray byteArr;
QBitArray bitArr;
QFile file(adress);
byteArr.readAll(file);
```

Convertion from bytes to bits:

```
BitArr.resize(8*byteArr.count());
for(int i=0; i<byteArr.count(); ++i)
    for(int b=0; b<8; ++b)
        bitArr.setBit(i*8+b, byteArr.at(i)&(1<<b));
```

Convertion from bits to bytes:

```
for(int i=0; i<bitArr.count(); ++i)
    byteArr[i/8] = (byteArr.at(i/8) | ((bitArr[i]?1:0)<<(i%8)));
```

And showing the result

```
ui->textBrowser->setText(QString(byteArr));
```

This code works fine perfect with ASCII letters.
But if I opened Unicode or UTf-8 of ANSI text, I have runtime error or wrong output. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Default `QString` constructor uses Latin1 encoding. Use `QString::fromUtf8(byteArr)` instead of `QString(byteArr)`. Conversion between QByteArray and QBitArray is not related to this issue.